# Get/copy multiple CID's from ipfs

Tags: nft, ipfs

Let's say I have 500 images stored on ipfs. Is there a way to get ALL of the CID's in one go for use later, or do I really need to copy each one by one?

Thanks in advance
Arnold

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to solve a similar issue.

I have 10,000 .json files uploaded in a folder, hosted and pinned on IPFS.

I want to copy each individual CID for each .json file and export it into a .txt file.

Did you figure out how to solve your issue?

EDIT1: I've found a method to retrieve CIDs with the CLI however the command stops running after 200 results.

```
ipfs refs [CID] >> CIDs.txt
```

EDIT2: Using the -r flag it gets a lot more CIDs but I get more than I need for some reason, I'm now trying to figure out how I can clean my CID list.

```
ipfs refs [CID] >> CIDs.txt -r
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/77167)